# Change UIView to UIScrollView

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview

I built in my storyboard this "myView" view controller scene:

[image]

I have a simple view containing an ImageView and a UILabel (that I reference in code through IBOutlets).

**What I want is transform this view to a scrollview and I was wondering if I could just adjust things in the storyboard for this purpose.**

I also tried to change the view to scrollview programmatically adding to the viewController's "ViewDidLoad" method the following:

```
CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];
scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,600);


self.view=scrollView;
```

But I'm not able to see my imageView and my label if I do So..**Why?**
I also tried (in storyboard) to assign the view (inside the "custom class" panel) the UIScrollView class but that's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found the solution, I changed the view type (identity inspector), but the `view` property of a `UIViewController` isn't a `UIScrollView`. So I get round this with casting the view to a `UIScrollView`:

```
[(UIScrollView *)self.view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add View to controller->*Identity Inspector*->Class-Change to *UIScrollView*

Resize your view
(self.urview as! UIScrollView).contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)